# Centering labels below buttons and the same spaces between buttons

Tags: android

I want to set layout in android as described here:

[image: Problem's description]

but I can only do it this way but it is not good enough:

[image: Solution so far]

Any ideas? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no good way to achieve what you want it only depend on your needs and constraints
For example if you have only three buttons so you can use a LinearLayout with an horizontal orientation and a weightSum of 90% with a centered gravity and you give each componnent a weight of 30% (eg. LinearLayout with vertical orientation) and after that you will have a dynamic height unless you constrain the label into single line or you can even marquee them